# How to put y axis number in Core Plot?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, core-plot

I would like my Scatter graph I am making with Core Plot library to show Y value near every point relative to X data.

I looked at CPTTestApp project from Core Plot examples, but I simply don't get it. First I thought the secret lies in

```
-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

method and I have implemented it in my project. Yes, I got points drawn, which is nice, but I found out this probably has nothing to do with values being shown near points....

This suspicion was confirmed when I opened Candlestick demo from Plot_Galley_Mac demo. There is no method from above and it shows numbers nicely!

If anyone can, please, help me. Otherwise, I would like to thank developers for sharing this library with us. Beside over usage of NSDecimal structure and a bit thin manual and reference data, this is fabulous project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for "data labels". CPTPlot has a number of properties that control the built-in labeling functions:

- `labelOffset`: distance between the point and the label
- `labelRotation`: rotation angle
- `labelTextStyle`: text style used to draw the labels
- `labelFormatter`: number (or date) formatter used to format the labels
- `labelShadow`: shadow properties applied to the labels

If the built-in labels don't meet your needs, you can create your own. Implement the `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method and return the desired label for each point. Custom labels can be any `CPTLayer` so you can make anything you want—text, images, or any custom layer that you create.